# How to remove Bramhahatya Sin

Tags: vedas, sin

Is there any method to clear Bramhahatya(Killing a Bramhana) Sin other than Ashwamedha Yagna?. Since Ashwamedha Involves being king and sacrificing horse which is violent method, and must be avoided if we can.

Comment: There are so many ways to get rid of the sin of Brahmahatya.  There are so many scriptures which say things like "If you do this then you'll get rid of the sin of Brahmahatya." or "If you do this then you'll get rid of the sin of intercourse with your guru's wife", etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What about its authenticity, the scriptures that mention such things are for those people who engage in such things as the Intercourse with mother equivalent. If such methods exists then why did Rama and Yudhishtira performed Ashwamedha?

Comment: There are numerous authentic scriptures that mention various methods of getting rid of the sin of Brahmahatya.

Comment: @Keshav The simplest method is to say 'Rama'. There cannot be an easier method ever. :D

Comment: Plus why do you want a method to remove Brahmahatya? It's not like you have..... (just kidding).

Comment: @Surya - I think Ramanama is just not enough to remove that sin, if that was to be true Rama wouldn't  perform Ashwamedha.I am asking this because I have infinite births, and karma from them. I could have killed a bramhana prior to this Brith.Plus there are many Kshatriya kings(Subedars) whose families are suffering till now because of the killing done by their ancestors, so I am asking that as a way to remove the karma from those families.

Comment: @Yogi You are highly underestimating the power of Rama Nama.  It is enough to absolve the sins of a crore janmas and the sins of all your ancestor.  Rama didn't use it because it was **his own** name, plus he wanted to set an example to all the Kings.  Also since it was Treta Yuga, Yajna was the main duty of people. In Kaliyuga chanting names is the main form of worship. The only thing is you can't use Rama nama as an **escape route** to commit sins.

Comment: @Surya I know ramanama is equivalent to A full Vishnu Sahastranama, but still I have doubt regarding clearing that sin. Since people had to perform Ashwamedha in previous yugas and we can escape by merely chanting ramanama? Quite Injust. Btw its not my ancestors I am talking about. Do you belong to ramanandi sect as you are agitated by my question on ramanama?

Comment: I don't belong to any sect. I just feel that you are unfortunate to not understand the power of it. Let it be Rama nama, Krsna nama, Siva Nama. If you have heard if Saint Tyagaraja you can read his songs which extol Rama nama. And I accept Tyagaraja's words without question.

Comment: @Yogi plus that is what I said. We cannot think that we can **escape** using Rama nama. If we purposely commit sins using Rama nama as a sin-remover that is a greater sin.

Comment: Love of God removes all sins. Chant the name of the Lord. The Lord's name removes all sins.

Comment: I agree with Surya about the power of Rama's name.  Especially in the Kali Yugs, where chanting of Sriman Narayana's names gives the result that could only be achieved by harder methods like Yagnas and Tapasya in earlier age.  Concerning your statement "I am asking this because I have infinite births, and karma from them.", Sharanagati can take care of that.

Comment: @Yogi: This link answers your question as per Goswami Tulasidasa's SriRamacharitamanasa. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/untruthfulness-as-the-unpardonable-sin/9288#9288

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Just give me one clear indication from Shastras, that Lord's name clears Bramhahatya pataka and I will be sure, about the Clearing of Sin, because Shastras are the ultimate Pramana.

Comment: @Jatin Give me same thing from Valmiki Ramayana and I will accept it, without any further reasoning.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Swamiji I agree with you, but I need specific answer for Bramhahatya pataka. Love of god is not authentic people rembember god in Bad times and forget God in Good times or Average times. It is very very rare and Difficult to Actually love god with Nishkama Bhakti Yoga as it Involves giving up the Selfishness which is the root cause of manas(Ego).

Comment: See Sankara's commentary on Gita verse 18.66. It is actually one of his longest commentaries of any Gita verse as this verse sums up the Gita. In his commentary he actually brings up the example of the sin of killing a brahmin. See also Gita 12.25 "...of words I am the monosyllable 'Om.' Of sacrifices I am the sacrifice of japa;..." And also Gita 12.8...

Comment: A minor point of order - aswamedha is forbidden in kali yuga.

Comment: @moonstar2001 do you have any supoorting evidence for your claim?

Comment: Yogi - i am sure you can research.

Comment: @Surya I have created a chatroom for discussion on this Topic

Comment: Also - rama nama is not just equivalent to Vishnu 1000. It is verily a tAraka mantra (one that allows us to transcend birth and death; unless one is absolved of ALL sins including those that you are worried about, one cannot be liberated). So rAma nAma is indeed a remedy. You will find commentary on Rama Nama in sAra tAropanishad, rAmatApanyOpanishad, adhyAtma rAmayaNa etc.

Comment: @Yogi where is it?

Answer (score 10):

There are many methods to remove Brahmahatya Sin and visiting Kasi (Varanasi) is one among them. This is described in [Chapter 182 - Mahatmya of Kasi Tirtha of Matsya Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-182/topic-1).

> आदेहपतनाद्यावत् क्षेत्रं यो न विमुंचति। 
>  **न केवलं ब्रह्महत्या**
> प्राकृता च निवर्त्तते।। १६ ।।
>   प्राप्य विश्वेश्वरं देवं न सा
> भूयोऽभिजायते। 
>  अनन्यमानसो भूत्वा योऽविमुक्तं न मुंचति।। १७॥
> तस्य देव: सदा तुष्टः सर्वान् कामान् प्रयच्छति। 
>  द्वारं
> यत्सांख्ययोगानां स तत्र वसति प्रभुः।। १८ ।।
>
> **One who goes there anytime is purified of the sin of even killing a
> Brähmana.** One who continually resides there, for all his life, unmoved
> in mind, is not only purified of his sin committed in this life, but
> **also of his Brahmahatyā sin in his previous birth**, and attains Visveswara (Siva) and does not get any other births. He gets the favour of Siva and all
> his desire are fulfilled, and he gets the same end as the knower of
> Sāmkhya does. He remains there all his lives and never quits it.

Comment: If visiting kashi would've removed this sin then why didn't any of the courtsmen or the wise men with Shri rama and Dharmaraja Yudhishtir tell them about this they could've easily avoided Ashwamedha Yagna. I think it must be `Mahatmya of Kashi Tirtha`  instead of `Mahatya`.

Comment: @Yogi Well, there are many ways to remove this sin but i think Aswamedha Yagna would give still some more benefits with removing Brahma hatya Dosha. So, Kings would choose this rather than visiting Kasi though visiting Kasi too remove many sins. I think Varna also plays a major role here.

Comment: Lets disscuss it here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39339/disscussion-on-bramhahatya-sin

Answer (score 6):

In [Mahabharata, Anushashan Parva, SECTION XXV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a025.htm), Yudhishthira has asked to Bhishma about the greatness of sacred waters. In this context Bhishma  told the story in which Sage Angiras has described the greatness of sacred waters to Gautama. According to Sage Angiras bathing in some sacred waters one can be freed from the sin of Brahmanicide.

> By bathing, after a fast of three days and purifying the mind of all evil passions, in the large lake of Bhrigu Kunda, one becomes **cleansed of even the sin of Brahmanicide**.
>
> Bathing in Asmaprishtha and Niravinda mountains and Kraunchapadi,--all three in Gaya--one becomes **cleansed of the sin of Brahmanicide**. A bath in the first place cleanses one of a single Brahmanicide; a bath in the second cleanses one of two offences of that character; and a bath in the third cleanses one of three such offences.
>
> Repairing to Indratoya in the vicinity of the mountains of Gandhamadana and next to Karatoya in the country called Kuranga, one should observe a fast for three days and then bathe in those sacred waters with a concentrated heart and pure body. **By doing this, one is sure to acquire the merit of a Horse-sacrifice**.
>
> Bathing in Ganga hrada and the tirtha known by the name of Utpalavana and daily offering oblations of water there for a full month to the Pitris, **one acquires the merit of a Horse-sacrifice**.
>
> Bathing in the confluence of the Ganga and the Yamuna as also at the tirtha in the Kalanjara mountains and offering every day oblations of water to the Pitris for a full month, **one acquires the merit that attaches to ten Horse-sacrifices**.
>
> Bathing in Utpataka and then in Ashtavakra and offering oblations of water to the Pitris every day for twelve days in succession, abstaining the while from food, **one acquires the merits of a Horse-sacrifice**.
>
> Observing a fast for three days and bathing in the tirtha known as Kulya and reciting the sacred mantras that go by the name of Aghamarshana, **one attains the merit of a horse-sacrifice**.

Comment: Well I know that horse Sacrifice clears Bramhahatya sin but, in cases like Bathing in Ganga It is not clear if we can clear Bramhahatya Sin(i don't know if inderict merit of Ashwamedha clears bramhahatya sin), why is more importance given to the lakes rather than ganga?

Comment: @Yogi Yes it is not clearly declared that bathing in Ganges, Brahma hatya sin will be removed but it clearly indicates that that Brahma hatya sin will be removed because bathing in Ganges is equal to Ashvamedh and Ashvamedh is way to remove this sin.

Comment: You cannot say that indirect merit would clear a sin. That is a possibility we need to confirm it.Also why do you think more importance to some lake rather than Ganges?

Comment: @Yogi well I will give more details about Bhrigu kund. I need some more time. Still I believe we should grab indirect notions of our scriptures because there are lot of such indications are available in scriptures.

Comment: @Yogi I have unable to find any references so I have asked a question about it here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14465/what-is-the-importance-of-bhrigu-kunda