# Bramhahatya / Brahma Hathi Dosham

Tags: belief

In temples we can find in pillars a monkey type animal in  sitting posture. When we go round the pillar there is a saying that dhosham will catch. How to get rid of this dhosham?
Another instance when the sacred thread of a Brahmin is cut by force, a severe brahama hathi dhosham will catch. Any parikarams for this? What will be the duration of this dhosham in years?

Comment: A part of your question("any parikarams") is already answered here http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11344/how-to-remove-bramhahatya-sin. If I have interpreted the parikarams word correctly.

Comment: @ Yogi  thanks for quoting from matshya purana. A person cannot get rid of brahma hathi dhosham. He has to take birth from small isects, reptiles, animals, birds  and then human being. This I came to know in a discourse in a temple in Bangalore before 7 years.

Comment: well bramhahatya can be paid off by doing ashwamedha if not possible then by doing Vishnu sahastranaam because it showers phala of 1000 ashwamedhas

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan There are many methods by which you can get rid of Brahma Hatya Dosham.

Comment: @ yogi Vishnu sahasranama I will recite every Saturday. Brahma hatya dosham cannot be paid off so easily. The sin will continue for  seven generations. Ashwameda is impossible nowadays. I think King Dasaratha did last. Brahman Janam is the gift by GOD to attain mukthi. To be utilised properly this janam.

Comment: @ The Destroyer You have mentioned methods only but not mentioned what method and cited any sources from bagavadhas.