# What is the importance of Bhrigu Kunda?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, upanishads

In [Mahabharata, Anushashan Parva, SECTION XXV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a025.htm), it is mentioned that by bathing in Bhrigu Kunda after fasting of three days, Brahmanacide (Brahma hatya) sin can be removed as I discuss in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11344/how-to-remove-bramhahatya-sin/14255#14255).

> By bathing, after a fast of three days and purifying the mind of all evil passions, in the large lake of Bhrigu Kunda, one becomes cleansed of even the sin of Brahmanicide.

My question is why Bhrigu Kunda has so much importance? Is there any story mentioned in scriptures about it?

Answer (score 5):

[The original Sanskrit](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_13_u.htm) somehow uses chapter 26 for the translation provided. You might be interested to find the word Bhṛgutuṅga is used.

According to the [Clay Sanskrit Library - notes on Ramāyana’s first book](http://www.claysanskritlibrary.org/excerpts/bala/bala-notes.php)

> Bhṛgutunda: This literally means “Bhṛgu’s belly” or “Bhṛgu’s navel.” Tunda is marked as a doubtful reading in the text; the most common variant is bhṛgutuṅga. The commentators agree that this is a place, but they interpret it somewhat differently. According to Ct, it refers to the specific peak of a mountain called Bhṛgutuṅga. Cr, on the other hand, thinks that is a “place associated with Bhṛgus.” Cg, who has the same reading as the critical text, understands, “on the inside — the belly (tunda) — of the slope of Bhṛgu’s mountain.”

According to the Purāṇic Encyclopaedia:

> Bhṛgutuṅga: A peak on which the sage Bhṛgu performed tapas. Ṛcīka had lived there with his wife and children. (Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, Bālakāṇḍa, 61st Sarga)

Comment: Thanks for answering but how can one bathe in the peak of mountain? I think there is some kunda or lake where one can bath. I am looking for that lake.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe there is a lake “on the inside” of the mountain ? I also don't know why the translator used Kunda, while the oroginal Sanskrit only uses that word in association with Nandi, for chapter 26.

Comment: When I am reading orginal sanskrit from here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13026.htm , it have  महाह्रद उपस्पृश्य भृगुतुङ्गे तव अलॊलुपः
     तरिरात्रॊपॊषितॊ भूत्वा मुच्यते बरह्महत्यया

Comment: Yes, this is the same as the Sanskrit in the link I provided: mahāhrada upaspṛśya bhṛgutuṅge tv alolupaḥ | trirātropoṣito bhūtvā mucyate brahmahatyayā. I am also starting to doubt the use of the word “lake”.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct for me too. But in that particular chapter discussion is going on the greatness of Tirthas and rivers. That's why I think that there must be some lake or kunda where one can bath and so looking for the same.

Comment: Some further research indicates that “mahāhrada” refers to “a great tank or pool”, upaspṛśya to “having touched” and bhṛgutuṅge is in the locative case, so it could definitely refer to “having touched a great lake in or on bhṛgutuṅga”. They question is, where is the mountain located? According to Monier-Williams, somewhere in the Himālaya or in the Vindhya.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for scriptural reference of the same lake.