# How can bhagwan hear me?

Tags: mantras

If i pray to some god like Ganesha or Shiva by using their mantra like om nama shivaya what is the logic behind that he hears us? what does this actually means to chant a mantra? It seems like according to Vedas all the deities are only a representation of natural forces and nature itself, so how the energy listen to someones prayer? Are they conscious? if yes how? if no, there is no such thing as god I think. How can nature or say the universe be conscious of some human's prayer?

Comment: Am not sure if you know there is a country named Nauru, but until unless someone tells you or you yourself explore it you will never know about it right? Similarly in order to know the existence of God or find out the truth, you yourself have to explore your inner self, no one else can do it on your behalf, others can only guide you.

Comment: "does this actually means to chant a mantra? It seems like according to Vedas all the deities are only a representation of natural forces and nature itself, so how the energy listen to someones prayer?" is the scientific speculation which is [not allowed](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/292/277) here. "Are they conscious?" Yes, Prajnanam Brahman - Aitareya Upanishad 3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If God is both omniscient and omnibenevolent, then, why do we need to pray?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21079/if-god-is-both-omniscient-and-omnibenevolent-then-why-do-we-need-to-pray)