# If Brahman is unattached, why does It remain attached to a devotee?

Tags: philosophy, gods, worship, brahman, prayer

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21032/2995) to the [Riddle of Epicurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicurus#Epicurean_paradox) says:

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, **because I remain detached like one unconcerned in their midst.**
>
> Gita 9.9
>
> **There is, however, one exception.**
>
> Whoever, being devoted to me solely, engage themselves always in contemplation and worship of Me - to such ever-steadfast devotees I ensure the procurement of all their wants (Moksha) and **the preservation of** their assets (**worldly interests**).
>
> Gita 9.22
>
> **God helps only His devotees.**

Why does or Why should a devotee get a special pass to getting their prayers answered? Doesn't it negate the answerer's earlier statement that "Brahman is unattached"?

Also, is the implication here that non-devotees don't get their wishes fulfilled or their 'worldly interests' preserved?

And what does it mean when a devotee's prayers don't get answered in this context? Or that's not a possibility because the claim being made here is that a devotee's prayer will be answered at any cost?

Comment: If you had 10 kids, and 9 of them go around playing with everyone and earning money and spending on worldly things, but 1 just sticks to you and doesn't leave your lap and is content with whatever you give him, wouldn't you take care of that child's needs. Does it mean you hate the other children, or that you won't give them what they need, or that you give this 1 child extra tasty food? God is unconcerned as to WHO becomes the devotee. He is not unconcerned about devotees. If any of the other 9 children decide they won't leave mom's side, she will take up responsibility of caring for them.

Comment: For the record Ramanujacharya doesn't interpret Yoga and Kshema in Gita verse 9.22 as referring to worldly prosperity, he interprets them as referring to Moksha.

Comment: Among all students in the class, why does the one that studies the best and writes the best stand first in class and progress accordingly in life? Isn't the teacher supposed to be impartial? Aren't all children in the class equal? Why are some students held back and why are some students dragging their feet in life with mediocre success? It's all the teacher's fault!

Answer (score 3):

The non-attachment of Brahman to creation is due to lust, greed etc. As soon as these impediments are removed God attracts man. Devotees are those Jivas who have succeeded in removing those impediments.

> Sri Ramakrishna: '..But as I said just now, one must live in holy
>   company and pray unceasingly. One must weep for God. When the
>   impurities of the mind are thus washed away, one realizes God. The
>   mind is like a needle covered with mud, and God is like a magnet. The
>   needle cannot be united with the magnet unless it is free from mud.
>   Tears wash away the mud, which is nothing but lust, anger, greed and
>   other evil tendencies, and the inclination to worldly enjoyments as
>   well. As soon as the mud is washed away, the magnet attracts the
>   needle, that is to say, man realizes God. Only the pure in heart see
>   God.'

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna April 9, 1882

Comment: "The non-attachment of Brahman to *creation*..." - creation here means jeevas? 'Devotees are those Jivas who have succeeded in removing those impediments.' - I don't think that's true, isn't everyone at some position or other in the race? BTW, since you are long time user here, can you write an answer to [this post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/944/2995) on meta?