# Does god have compassion and empathy or is he a totally emotionless karmic intelligence system

Tags: vedas, ramayana, gods, kali-yuga, paramatma

I have seen Sadhguru saying in one of his video bytes, that god wouldn't even lift the tip of his little finger for you. Is that true? Is parabrahm a higher karmic intelligence conscious system without empathy and compassion? Especially, at any given minute, there are billions of people praying to him for their well being. Does parabrahm take note of our individual prayers? And will he do anything about the prayers? Or asking him for anything through simple prayers is futile? Since the world operates based on karmic order.

Comment: It is not an intelligence system. Intelligence runs much below to Aatman, which this Param Brahma is.

Comment: You may only ask one q at a time. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Good question. I've thought about this for a long time.

Comment: @Santhosh i believe Sadhguru hadnt gone throguh srimad bhagavatam, He had lifted Govardhan Giri for Nandagram Villagers.. Read S.B. Canto 10 of sri krishna charitram it was for his devotee he performed more lilas, Please follow gita and srimad bhagavatam to increase bakthi and he will come to you, he is already doing it for you needed to be aware of his presence inside you and lifting your body and making you function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have any Hindu philosophers attempted to solve the Riddle of Epicurus?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/have-any-hindu-philosophers-attempted-to-solve-the-riddle-of-epicurus)

Comment: this is a common question with a simple answer - Bhagavan has compassion for those who ask for compassion, and is emotionless karmic system for those who don't. Brahma sutras clearly states this.

Answer (score 2):

Only those who practice spiritual disciplines are guaranteed complete protection.

> Whoever, being devoted to me solely, engage themselves always in
> contemplation and worship of Me - to such ever steadfast devotees I
> ensure the procurement of all their wants (salvation) and the
> preservation of their assets.

**Gita 9.22**

Others have to live according to their karma. This is the general idea. Of course since Brahman is self willed, I would not go so far as the Sadhguru and say that He will not lift a single finger. He might but the possibility of that is highly unlikely. In general God does not interfere in the running of the universe. It is Prakrti that runs the universe.

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
> again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
> owing to Nature's sway over them.

**Gita 9.8**

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, because **I remain detached
> like one unconcerned in their midst.**

**Gita 9.9**

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
> of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
> revolve.

**Gita 9.10**

Comment: Can you please add any specific instances (if there are any) where Ishwara might have overturned somebody's karma?

Comment: Specifically, I heard that Goddess Kali could have overturned the suffering of Sri Ramakrishna if he had asked her, but he did not ask for some reason.

Comment: Vivekananda requested Ramakrishna to ask Ma Kali to cure his disease. At first Ramakrishna refused. After much pestering Ramakrishna told Ma kali about his difficulty in eating due to the throat cancer. Mother scolded him saying that aren't you eating food through millions of mouths of jivas. Ramakrishna later on blamed Vivekananda's pestering for the scolding.

Comment: I had downvoted for you personal opinion only devotees protected

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay May be Goddess have given same dose of advaita to Sri ramakrishna  but I sincerely believe that goddess Maa Durga gave Darshan to sri ramakrishna due to his persistent effort for that i respect ramakrishna but his philosophy I'm allergic

Answer (score 1):

God is referred to have u soooooooo much compassion alot a lot and a lot, It couldn't be counted and nobody knows why he is sooo kind, Sri Kanchi Periyava says he is the Cow and we are his calves, If we tie both of them The mother Cow cries for her baby and the calf for our mother, He has soo much Compassion that he helps the ones who do sincere Bhakti whatever kharmic deeds he might have performed, he shows them the true way,he saves them from all disasters, He justs says have complete faith on me,

I would like to tell you the story of Balichakravathy here

Bhali is a very compassionate he donates anything which people ask for, He never speaks anything other than truth ( This was shown in one of his conversation with his guru Shukra, Shukrachariyar knows that the Dwarf is not a human he is Vishnu himself and warns him not to give anything he asks for, Bhali having promised to give whatever that dwarf asks for says if one speaks the truth there won't be any bad thing that could happen.
The story continues after Amrutha Mathanam( Churning of Parkadal)
Devar or sons of Aditi after getting Amrutha forgot their Guru Brihaspati ( if one forgets the guru he will have to face severe consequences) whereas Bali who prayed his Guru drove all the Devar from Heaven and he ruled all the three worlds, Aditi mother of Devar was very much worried by this so she went to Narayana to ask for help, Narayana said your children forgot their Guru and are suffering and you have asked me so he said I can't go Like Vishnu to fight him I must be your child so that I could justify Dharma(Vishnu could justify his fight against Bali for his brother Indra). So he went to Bali ( as Bali is good he never wanted to kill him instead asked Bali for Bhiksha, Then Bali after seeing Vishnu's true form said "I UNDERSTOOD ONE THING" Bhagwan asked" WHAT DID YOU UNDERSTAND BALI?" Bali replied " ME GIVING EVERYONE WHAT THEY ASK FOR AND ME SPEAKING THE TRUTH ALWAYS IS YOUR KRIPA AND I AM NOTHING IN IT, IT WAS YOUR BELSSING NARAYANA", Then Vishnu said" BALI YOU ARE SOO GOOD SO I AM GONNA ASK YOU AS BHIKSHA ,(here we must note that Vishnu never killed Bali, he asked Bali as a bhakta that too he asked him as Bhiksha) then he took Bali to a spiritual world and said he would stand outside his darbar and whenever he wanted to see him he just had to think him and Vishnu would come to him.

So this shows how compassionate he is... he helped Aditi too even when Devar performed bad deeds ( they forgot their Guru Brihaspati) and Gave Bhali moksha too, There are many instances in Bhagawatham where his swabhawan is shown, You can read them

Harikatha link- ( I couldn't tell the full story you can hear it here ) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=robrFBrPRpg
you can study Bhagawatham here- https://vedabase.io/en/

Atlast I would say the world does follow the path of Dharma, You know your mother does love you when you do even bad deeds right? the same way When you realize your mistakes and surrender yourself to Bhagwan, he will make you pure and free you from sansar or worldly things and saves you from everything

Comment: Thank you. Your answers are really satisfying.

Comment: Good to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The question is who is God and why should you ask him any favors. Is this Krishna or Jesus or any one of the thousands of gods we know of? If you are Hindu and one day decide to ask Jesus for help, does it mean he won't because you are Hindu? Who is this unknown, unseen personality that we send our prayers to and expect him or her to answer. And if you feel this is an all knowing and loving force, then why even bother asking when such a benevolent being, who already knows what's best for you. Are you really sure you know what you desire better than God? Is that the reason he/she is simply smiling away at the millions of prayers that float around?

Prayer is a short cut we have devised and one that nobody knows for sure if it works or not.  More often than not it seems to not work, but I suppose what's the harm in asking, right? The truth is that if God exists then we both overestimate his power and well as underestimate his power.  Asking for something is a silly endeavor.  You have an experience - let's say it's God given - now you want to alter it so badly. Why? It's just an experience - one that will pass by you eventually.  If you wish it away, you will end up with another one and then another one.  There is no end to this until life itself.  How you handle this is the true karma.  The answers (prayers) are in your actions (which is really karma).  Karma is not only the influencer, it is also the destiny.  And God wants you to define it with actions, not prayer. So I don't think he really tries to answer your prayer.  So either way if God exists or not, life is the same - hence an atheist lives as well as a Hindu, Christian, agnostic, etc.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, with authentic citations.