# Is god ultimately responsible for cancer?

Tags: gods, evil, disease

Does Hinduism have a monotheistic god? If yes, is he/she/it ultimately responsible for diseases like cancer?

On one hand scientists are trying hard to find a cure for known variants of cancer and god on the other hand seems busy creating new variants.

How do Hindus reconcile the two?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Feel free to take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have any Hindu philosophers attempted to solve the Riddle of Epicurus?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/have-any-hindu-philosophers-attempted-to-solve-the-riddle-of-epicurus)

Answer (score 1):

God in any religion is the absolute all knowing and omnipresent creator. He doesn’t have any particular form but he can exist in various forms at the same time depending on his different attributes. The multiple hindu gods are significators of the same philosophy.

And God doesn’t create anything evil just to make you or me suffer. He’s not a sadistic psycho. He just created multiple systems of everything, which will function according to the universal karmic system. Human body is one such system. The Good things/sufferings that we experience in this present life are mostly results of both past life good or bad karma and the present life choices of the person. It is a system that keeps functioning independently. Now can god stop your illness and make you normal again? He definitely can. but, are you calling for him loud enough? If he can’t hear you, he doesn’t even move the nail of his little finger for you. Now, How to get gods attention amongst all the zillions of mortal beings in this universe? It is either through enlightenment of the self or some other ways like “mantra japa” prescribed in the scriptures. Neither of the two procedures can be a proven fact until we test it ourselves.

Comment: You should cite sources.