# Does Every Jiva Go Through Approximately Same Amount Of Pain & Suffering Before Moksh

Tags: moksha, life, jiva

I think that Vivekanand said every jiva eventually reaches enlightenment after many lifetimes, and he also said there is no freedom in maya, everyone is made to go through things, behave a certain way, reap certain karm-phals, and so forth.

Do Hindu texts tell that each jivatman goes through the same amount of pain and suffering over lifetimes ?

Cause then this would seem more fair and justice overall.

When our lives are horrible and we’re dealing with very difficult things, I guess it would help to know that everybody suffers the same amount, over numerous lifetimes.

Is this stated anywhere in our Hindu texts ?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of pain and suffering? See this [Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/why-does-god-allow-us-to-suffer) first then answer....

Comment: @Rāmachandra I didn’t realize I have to go in and click the approve edit thing to make the edit go through, just selected approve right now.  The post is much better w/ that, thx ! And I fully agree w/ your note about Christian word “soul” vs jiva in Hinduism 