# Brahmanda Purana English translation

Tags: puranas, brahma, translation-request

I am trying to find a proper English translation of Brahmanda Purana. I have seen one in [archive.org](http://www.archive.org/stream/BrahmandaPurana/BrahmandaPuI_djvu.txt). The translation is done by author Dr. G.V. Tagare. But it has omitted multiple verses saying defective text (e.g., 17-28).

Also its translation is pretty horrible and very difficult to understand.

I could not get any other translation other than the one above even after extensive googling. It would be really great help, if someone can point towards right translation.

Comment: What you linked to is just volume 1 of Tagare's translation.  (I think that's the only volume available in archive.org.) I could write an answer giving all five volumes if you like.  But Tagare's translation is the only unabridged English translation of the Brahmanda Purana.

Comment: Thank you very much.Could you please give me link for those translations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better or worse, the only unabridged English translation of the Brahmanda Purana is the one by G.V. Tagare, published by Motilal Banarsidass.  But what you linked to is just Volume 1 of Tagare's translation.  In my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5301/36), I gave links to all five volumes:

- [Volume 1](http://gdurl.com/rjgr/download) (from DLI)
- [Volume 2](http://gdurl.com/MGEB/download) (from DLI)
- [Volume 3](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12922) (DSpace)
- [Volume 4](http://issuu.com/nitai/docs/brahmanda_pu_iv) (ISSUU)
- [Volume 5](http://gdurl.com/CAK5/download) (from DLI)

Here is the [table of contents](http://tinyurl.com/kqrhhvs) and [index](http://tinyurl.com/laxj5a5) for the translation.

The online proofread version of the [Brahmanda-Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana) and the [Lalitopakhyana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya) also includes an interwoven Puranic glossary.

Note that volumes 1, 2, and 5 were taken from the Digital Library of India (DLI), downloaded as PDF's and then uploaded to Google Drive; if you're interested you can see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/792/36) for details on how to download books from DLI in PDF format.  Also the link for Volume 3 is on DSpace, the digital repository for the West Bengal Public Library Network.  Unfortunately the West Bengal Public Library website is down at the moment, but hopefully it will be back soon.

By the way, if you don't like Tagare's translation, you can read [this extremely abbreviated translation](http://www.gita-society.com/section3/HinduPuranas16.htm) of the Brahmanda Purana (and the other 17 Mahapuranas).

Comment: @sysinit You're welcome.  By the way, I highly recommend that you look at the Digital Library of India.  You may find a lot of books that interest you.

Comment: When i was in bangalore , I could able to see all puranas translated into local languages(Kannada,tamil etc) . I dont see respective online copies either. There is no online english translation other than tagare to fall back on.

Comment: @sysinit There's no other physical book English translation either besides Tagare.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on unrelated thread.Even for Vayu purana , there is no other english translations besides one from Tagare?

Comment: @sysinit No, there's also this translation of the Vayu Purana: http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/vayu-purana-sanskrit-text-with-english-translation-in-two-volumes-IDK853/ But I don't think there's an online version of that translation, only of the Motilalal Banarsidass (Tagare) one.

Comment: Thanks . Do you have link for complete Vayu purana from tagare.? All pdfs which I got contains only first 50 pages.

Comment: @sysinit You can read both volumes of the Vayu Purana on DSpace, the digital repository of the West Bengal Public Library Network: http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/simple-search?query=vayu&submit=Go

Comment: Sorry to ask but which volume contains Adhyatma Ramayana?