# How many sons did Kesari have, other than Sri Hanuman?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

Shuka, Ravana's aide, describes the individual strengths of the various commanders in the army of monkeys, mentioning their names one by one, in detail, in Yuddha Kanda of Srimad Ramayana.

[While describing Sri Hanuman](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga28/yuddhasans28.htm#Verse10), Shuka says that Sri Hanuman was the eldest son of Kesari.

> ज्येष्ठः केसरिणः पुत्रो वात आत्मज इति श्रुतः |
> हनूमान् इति विख्यातो लन्घितो येन सागरः || ६-२८-१०
>
> This monkey, by whom the ocean was traversed, is the eldest son of Kesari. He is known as the son of wind-god and famously called as Hanuman.

Can anybody tell me how many sons did Kesari have, other than Sri Hanuman?

Answer (score 15):

Kesari and Anjana had in total 5 sons out of which Lord Hanuman was the eldest one. The names of other sons of King Kesari were:

1. Matiman
2. Shrutiman
3. Ketuman
4. Dhrtiman

Also, unlike Lord Hanuman, these all were married and had kids. All this is mentioned under Brahamand Purana. Apart from other things, this purana also contains the details of the family tree of Kesari and about other things in the life of Lord Hanuman.

Following extract from Brahamand Purana verse 223 to 230 shows the same:

[image]

However, as per another website article listed in following links, it was mentioned that Lord Hanuman has one more brother called 'Gatimaan'. Although, they also mentioned their source as Brahamand Purana, but I am not able to currently find his details.

- [Link 1](http://hindi.speakingtree.in/slideshow/hanumanji-ke-paanch-bhai-bhi-the/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0)
- [Link 2](http://hindi.speakingtree.in/slideshow/hanumanji-ke-paanch-bhai-bhi-the/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%BC%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80)

Also, link of Brahamand Purana can be found in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6751/1018). The verses stated above can be found in Book 2 of the series.

Comment: Unlike Hanuman? Hanuman is married.

Comment: @Wikash_  Source?