# Apart from Divya Prabandam scriptural references to Thiruthangal Nindra Narayana Perumal Temple

Tags: vishnu, puranas, identification-request

The ever merciful Lord Narayana (Mahavishnu) is dedicated to His true devotees. Tales abound of Him personally coming to bless, serve and / or relive his devotees of their problems.

He took on the form of a woman, to help Sant Sakkubai to fulfil her desire to visit Pandharpur, while serving her family.  He appeared before Pundalik and patiently stood on the brick pushed towards Him with His hands on the hips, while Pundalik finished serving his aged parents. He came all the way from Dwaraka to near Puri to bear witness to a transaction in which His devotee was unable to claim his rightful dues – Sakshigopal. And so many other stories.

In Divya Prabandham, Thiruthangal Nindra Narayana Perumal Temple near Sivakashi, Tamil Nadu, is mentioned as one of the 108 Divya Desams.

**My question is apart from Divya Prabandham is the story of Nindra Narayan Perumal mentioned in any other Puranas or scriptures?And what is the full story?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This excerpt](https://ia801604.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/18/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.170212/2015.170212.1991-November-Sapthagiri_jp2.zip&file=2015.170212.1991-November-Sapthagiri_jp2/2015.170212.1991-November-Sapthagiri_0012.jp2&scale=8.314194577352472&rotate=0) from a journal paper says that Thiruthangal is mentioned in the Brahmanda Purana:

> The eighth chapter of kshetra kanda contained in the Brahmanda Purana has given a pen-picture of this hallowed place. Puroora Chakravarthy, a prudent and upright ruler of Bharatavarsha renounced his kingdom in favor of his sons with the avowed intention of seeking eternal bliss.  He sought guidance from the sages to the appropriate place for performing a penance.  The sapient sages rightly directed him to Thiruthangal where he conducted an austere penance.  He was rewarded with a darshan of Mahavishnu who duly granted him salvation.

In any case, you can read the Brahmanda Purana using the links in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6751/36).  I'm not sure what part of the Brahmanda Purana constitutes the Kshetra Kanda.  It's possible that this story is only found in some recensions of the Brahmanda Purana.