# Varaha Avatar and Swetha Varaha

Tags: vishnu

it is still not clear whether the Varaha Avatar is the same as Swetha Varaha that is related to Swetha varaha kalpam. Can some one be decisive in their answer?

Comment: Very very close:—https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13635/why-is-present-kalpa-named-as-sweta-varaha-kalpa