# What is the purpose of Venkateshwar incarnation?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, venkateshwara

Generally, Gods incarnate for some specific reasons like, destruction of some evil forces, to enlighten people with knowledge, establish dharma, etc. We have seen the same in case of most of Lord Vishnu's incarnations like Lord Rama, Lord Krishna, Lord Varaha, Lord Narasimha, Lord Parasurama, Lord Vamana, etc.

But I can't really understand about what is the purpose of Venkateshwar incarnation. I have read the story of Venkateshwar incarnation and I know about how the curse, etc things happen and how he spent His time on earth but generally the incarnations, curses, etc happen for a bigger purpose in future. So, can somebody please enlighten me on this.

Comment: can't cite you references but his true purpose is to serve his devotees in kaliyuga and came to earth on pretext of marrying Padmavathi aka Vedavati.

Comment: I think only marriage would be a very small cause for an incarnation. These kind of things generally go along with the main purpose but they are not the root cause.

Comment: But according to scriptures,  Krishna told Yashoda that she would see His marriage in her next birth (Vakula Devi). Yeah, these things might not be the main purpose but priests of Tirumala reiterate that He came to earth just to serve his devotees. It is believed that He will wake up from Seshachalam Hill and go to Vaikunta on Garuda which too comes from Seshachalam Hills. (1/2)

Comment: There's view of Seshachalam Hills at tiruchanur ammavari temple or vakuladevi aalayam, which looks like Vishnu sleeping on these hills. At the end of Kaliyuga, he wakes up from these hills and on Garuda he will go to vaikuntam. This also happens only when a devotee comes to him just to see him without taking any vows. But it looks no devotee went to him without taking any vow till now. (2/2).

Comment: @AnilKumar I'm sure there are countless devotees who go to Tirupati without taking vows.  I went to Tirupati yesterday without taking vows.  By the way, I went on a Thursday, so I got to see his eyes and feet without ornaments.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Not countless devotees may be few. You are staunch devotee of Vishnu so there's no surprise that you visited Him without taking any vow :) . A priest in local Venkateswara Temple of my city said this to me. I'm not sure about last statement but former two statements may happen at the end of Kaliyuga. He told me this was mentioned in Aagama Sastra. Yeah, Thursday it was **Nijaroopa Darshanam**. BTW, did you go to **Padmavathi Ammavari Karthika Brahmaostavam**?And among 7 hills of Tirumala,definitely Seshachalam Hills are more sacred and rich, even when compared to venkatachala

Comment: @AnilKumar No, the Brahmotsavam would have been far too crowded, so I skipped going to Thiruchannor.  But for the first time, I got to see the Adi Varahaswami temple, which I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2086/36 I don't know what you mean by "Seshachalam hills". Are you referring to the first hill of Tirumala?  Are you suggesting that the first hill of Tirumala is more sacred than the seventh hill where Venkateshwara is located?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Seshachalam hills are hills which Adisesha manifested. As they represent Adisesha, which is Vishnu himself, they are sacred. Venkatadri is important because Venkateswara resides there. Among the seven hills Seshachalam are more sacred. Those stretch of hills have  a legend associated with it. Also, do you know about seven sisters (shakti) of Venkateswara? Sarees are send to them   for any occasions (festivals) from Tirumala.

Comment: @AnilKumar I don't know what you mean by "Among the seven hills Seshachalam are more sacred".  The Seshachalam hills is another name for the seven hills of Tirumala - the seven hills together constitute the body of Adiseshan.  Venkatadri is one of the seven hills.  So what hill are you saying is more sacred than Venkatadri?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Sorry! I said something rather than what i wanted to convey. I mean "Shesadri" where we can see Him sleeping on it. All 7 hills are part of Seshachalam hills, which are stretched from Srisailam to Srikalahasti. All these 7 hills are sacred but this "seshadri" is little more sacred. Some saints like Ramanujacharya said one should not step on these Tirumala hills due to their sacredness. Ok you can see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjqxkMIqPWI) if you want to know how He slept on this hills.These seven hills represent seven hoods of Adisesha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan A local priest told me this importance of Seshadri, So, i'm not sure about scriptural basis for this.

Comment: The avatara is called "archavatara" meaning in the form of a deity.Main purpose of this incarnation is being available to devotees within reach. He chose Tirumala hills to reside because he felt bored residing in Vaikunta. Venkateshwara incarnation is not a "Vibhava" avatara like Krishna and Rama. Venkateshwara is Lord VIshnu himself. Therefore he is not listed in incarnations of the lord.

Comment: Lord Vishnu, in the form of Venkateshwara, and his consort are believed to have enshrined themselves at Tirumala Tirupati for the benefit of mankind. This phenomenon is called swayambhu loosely translated to mean "self-existent and established on earth of one's own accord, without any external cause". This link have more info: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120306082902AAfm8Jj

Answer (score 1):

Sri Venkateshwara was not an incarnation of Mahavishnu, he was Mahavishnu incarnate. As his Mangalacharan states 
श्री वैकुण्ठ विरक्ताय स्वामि पुष्करिणी तटे |
रमया रममाणाय वेन्कटेशाय मङ्गलम् ||
Getting displeased or bored f Shri Vaikunta, the lord came to the shores of Swami Pushkarani (the temple tank) where he frolics with His Consort.

Sri Venkatesh Mahatmyam narrates why Mahavishnu came down to Earth. At the beginning of Kali Yuga the great sages had gathered at Naimisharanya to perform a great Yagya for the benefit of humans. There was a debate as to who should be the Yagya Purusha he main deity, and it fell on the learned but arrogant sage Brighu.  By his austerities Brighu had eyes in the sole of his feet.

Brihju first went to Satya Loka. Brahma was not there and the arrogant sage sat on Brahma's throne.  When Brahma came he was furious and cursed Brighu. In turn Brighu cursed Brahma that in Kali Yuga there will not be any temples for your worship. In fact the only templf e where Brahma is worshiped is at Pushkar in Rajasthan.

Brighu the went to Kailasa. Shiva and Parvati were love making - and Nandi stopped Brighu.  An angry Brighu stormed into the inner chambers and cursed Shiva that since you are always only interested in lovemaking, no temple of yours will have your image.  You will be worshipped in the form of a Linga.

He then went to Vaikunta where Vishnu was sleeping. Brighu kicked Vishnu on His chest.  Vishnu woke up - O maharishi Brighu, my chest is like hardened rock, but your feet must be hurting.  Massaging Brighu's feet Vishnu pulled out the eyes in the soles of his feet.  Immediately he lost his arrogance, angered beyond sought Vishnu's forgiveness and declared him to be the Yagya Purusha.

But Lakshmi was angry and she quarreled with Vishnu - you no longer love me - here a good for nothing Brahmin kicks you on your chest where I reside and instead of punishing him you massage his feet and seek his forgiveness. You don't deserve me and so saying Lakshmi left Vaikunta. she came to the Venkatadri Hills and started living as a cowherdess. Without Lakshmi Vaikunta lost its lusture and charm and so following her and searching for her Srinivasa came to Venkatadri Hills. [Some of these aspects are sourced the TTD publication on the Story of Seven Hills]

Comment: This complete story whether true or not is of low quality, childish & whimsical which portrays both Gods & RIshi human like endowed with low intellect & immaturity. Seriously, do you think Lord VIshnu can get bored? He is personification of Aishwarya/Ananda. Do you think Lord Shiva & Parvati are busy in love making day in day out? Or Bhrigu Rishi signed a bond to get angry without any reason?

Comment: Further Lord Vishnu & Goddess are behaving like an average Kaliyuga husband wife full of drama? It can't be accepted. Well, you can say it is Leela after all. :P

Comment: please refer to the Venkatesha Mahatmyam.  Also please refer to the TTD publication on the Story of Tirumala.  Whether Gods can behave childishly and immaturely is not within our knowledge, because faith does not permit us to accept, but yes it can and is His Leela. The story further goes that in the absence of Lakshmi Shreenath was Shreeheen - i.e. the defender of Shree was without her.  Hence for His marraige with Padmavathy, He had to borrow 11,400,000 gold varahas from Kubera.  This loan was to be repaid at the end of Kaliyuga. Interest is paid annually - the temple collections.

Comment: @Rohit. The story is from Venkatachala Mahatmyam. Lord wanted to visit Bhuloka. So, he ordered the Garuda to take the River Viraja to the Sheshachalam hills. This is not childish or immature. This is not an unsourced citation. "Lord Vishnu & Goddess are behaving like an average Kaliyuga husband wife full of drama?" I can loads of them in Devi Bhagavata. Vishnu having Ganga and Saraswati as wives XD So, is it also leela? The story is true. Don't say without knowing the complete story. There are many such acts of God which are beyond our understanding.

Comment: Lord did not want to visit Bhulpka - this is not as per the Mahatmyam.  Bhoodevi approached Varahaswamy at his palace in Mount Meru. The Lord asked her what more she needed from Him.  He had raised her from the bottom of the ocean and placed her safely on the hood of Adi Sesha.  So she was now secure. However on her request He narrated that He was ever present on the southern bank of Swamipushkarini in the Divine Vimana Ananada.  He appears to all His devotees as the temple idol, but the Vimana cannot be seen by normal humans.  That is the reason He is Pratyaksha Kaliyuga Devata.

Comment: @SS I found it against integrity of Lord Vishnu & Shiva, that's why I couldn't accept.

Comment: I can appreciate your feelings - but all the Puranas have presented Shiva as the Adi Yogi as well as the greatest charmer of women. Whatever one may feel, the Eternal Charmer Sri Krishna was also a great seducer.  This comment is by logical deduction of the narrations in various Puranas. Whether this was done as a part of His leela or otherwise is a debatable point from human view.