# Can God(s) get bored?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, trinity

Boredom & loneliness is the byproduct of lack of inner taste of Self. When one identifies himself with something limited which he is not, one gets such feelings owing to lack of experience of bliss & self completedness. Incompleteness implies boredom or loneliness, hence Someone who is complete can never get bored. Otherwise Parshuram, Hanuman etc all would have got bored so far being still alive. They are complete in themselves, experiencing taste of Brahman in Turiya state is the reason they never get bored or feel lonely.

But [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/what-is-the-purpose-of-venkateshwar-incarnation) thread claims Lord Vishnu incarnate on earth owing to getting bored in Vaikuntha (one of the reason) what is the use of then aspiring for Vaikuntha if one get even bored there? Further it is hugely conflicting that Lord Vishnu can get bored!

So my question is what scriptures mention any case where God(s) got bored? I think It may be possible demigods could get bored as they are not enlightened but what about Trinity? Is there any case which tells trinity got bored?

Comment: Getting Bored is human's nature or feeling, It is law of Nature that people feels different feelings. But Laws of nature doesn't apply of Lord. He is away from all rules of Nature. Nature is under his control. he is not under control of nature like us.

Comment: The words used in the scriptures regarding Venkateshwara Swamy is 'विरक्तः'. The Sanskrit Word विरक्तः means averse, becoming indifferent, disinterested, passionless - may be one of those synonyms may be more apt to describe what I described as 'bored' in the reply to Sri Venkateshwara Swamy question.

Comment: When they get bored, they do "time-pass" on earth, which we call as "pastime" (*leela*). :-)

Comment: God may be looking bored to us but he doesn't get.

Comment: I don’t think they ever get bored. AFAIK people occasionally get bored and projecting their moods onto them sometimes, which is inaccurate

Answer (score 3):

> *"I think It may be possible demigods could get bored as they are not enlightened but what about Trinity? Is there any case which tells trinity got bored?"*

Let's assume that the trinity is one or the other way the "Supreme Brahman", which is the ultimate 'form' of the true self (*Atma*/आत्म).

If we translate,

- bored = disinterested (a kind of indifference)

Then **Yes**, the supreme one runs this world in a boring way only.

> प्रकृतिं स्वामवष्टभ्य विसृजामि पुनः पुनः। भूतग्राममिमं कृत्स्नमवशं प्रकृतेर्वशात् ।।
>   न च मां तानि कर्माणि निबध्नन्ति धनञ्जय। **उदासीन**वदासीनमसक्तं तेषु कर्मसु ।।
>
> BG 9.8, 9.9 - Keeping My nature (prakruti) under control, I create [& destroy] the world of beings again & again; which are helpless under the nature (prakruti); And O Arjuna, those actions (Karma-s) don't bind Me, as **"I" am indifferent (disinterested)** & detached to those actions

Typically one gets bored of something when it's repetitive & without any purpose. For Brahman, the *leela* of whole universe's creation/destruction is repetitive & [without any purpose](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19458/1049). It creates the exact same universe again and again with the exact same events and then destroys in exactly same way. Cross reference:

> BG 8.19 - This elementary world only happens again & again; Annihilates upon arrival of night, [and] originates upon arrival of day.

Comment: IMO- Disinterest & boredom are not synonymous. Disinterest - without any interest/will/desire but boredom is a condition where one is devoid of any interesting activity but aspire for it sub consciously to play. BTW, Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Rohit. *"boredom is a condition where one is **devoid of any interesting ** activity"* = "disinterested". :-) Anyways, the meaning you derive for "boredom", is still applicable to the verse mentioned in the answer. For the *Brahman*, any activity is *devoid of any interest*. Without any plan, [it just does things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S4ts.jpg).

Comment: You forgot "...But aspire for it subconsciously" :P . In more simple terms- Boredom is a condition where one is devoid of any **available** interesting activity when it is needed to play or enjoy.

Comment: Being Udasina and being bored not the same thing.

Comment: @Rickross, *udAsina* is translated as "disinterested". "Boring" is also translated as "disinteresting" (or uninteresting) at many places. If we translate "bored" as "tedious" or "not do-able" then this answer may not apply. That's why I have specified the translation assumed, before the verse.

Comment: @iammilind We use this word udAsina too often while speaking in Bengali. It does not mean bored. For bored we have Virakta and other words.

Comment: @Rickross, "उदास" is a common word among all Sanskrit based languages including Hindi. Sometimes people translate it as "depressed/disappointed", but that's not right. Because "depressed/disappointed" means हताश/निराश . The correct translation for "उदास" is **indifferent** or **unconcerned** (as per Gambhirananda). If you search these words for synonyms, then you may find "uninterested/disinterested" for sure. "Boredom" might be different for different people. But most will agree that one gets bored, when does something "not so interesting". Anyhow, I have edited the answer.

Comment: ...Ok ........ @iammilind