# What work does God do daily?

Tags: gods, time

What is God doing now, since God created this universe long ago?

Does God have daily work to do?

Let's consider what God is doing at this moment in time... I mean in the past many significant things were happening, like the killing of demons by different gods... so now god is free? Or if not, what might God be doing now?

Comment: He is sustaining the universe he created.

Comment: Related or duplicate of [When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/when-brahmas-day-ends-and-a-new-day-starts-does-the-previous-day-repeat-itself) ... and ... [Can God(s) get bored?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20176/1049).

Comment: depends. Which GOD you are talking about.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad any god , like routine of any god ?

Comment: @AmruthA if you say Lord Brahma he is Writing future of every karma of every soul. Lord Vishnu is looking at level of Dharm and Neeti in any lok. and Lord Shiva is associated with death and transformation. Lord Ganpati is looking at devotee who are worshiping him to remove any obstacle. Every GOD has its own work and there are million of soul in every lok.

Comment: @AmruthA As lord Vishnu is associated with Dharma and Neeti Right now there are the chance of him being on our planet Earth. Now exactly where he is I don't know.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad god is person who can do what ever he thinks ,, he can destroy evil why he has come to earth and maintain Dharma

Comment: @AmruthA If you understand God will not do any thing just like this. Whatever he does There is a strong reason for doing it. And Have you read or listen anywhere that GOD has killed any one without appearing in front of  person.

Comment: @AmruthA Whenever God has to kill the people who are following ADHARMA and ANEETI he has to do it physically. Now If we consider example of YOU and ME. If I need to give you answer of this question I have to be physically here and type the answer. Same law is applied to GOD. He has to kill all bad people and tell or explain other people what is DHARM and NEETI..

Comment: @AmruthA Is there anything else

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad he could have done blink of eye , but why we are not coming to know what he is doing now..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65247/discussion-between-praveen-gaikwad-and-amruth-a).

Comment: You need to understand lots of concepts in Hinduism to get **proper** answer for this question.

Comment: He does nothing.

Comment: Just check your to-do list or what all activities you did today. From your perspective that is what God does. Once you focus on your activities more and more the self awareness sinks in. You will get buried in jargon if you look outside your window in search of god. Once god creates you he is you and you are him. If anyone thinks otherwise you have found an alien among us. Either way you will learn.

Comment: @Rama27 if I am god , why am I suffering , and why I am not able to remove evil from world ?

Comment: All solutions are within you. If you look outside for solution they will be temporary in nature. If you find a solution within it is permanent. Take care and All the best!.

Comment: You can ask a new question if you want answer to the question "Which demons did demons kill today". Bounty is not the correct way to add a new question after it received multiple answers and accepting one of the answers, but when you post that question, give more clear description of which god and what do you mean by killing a rakshasa, that seem a vague question to me and not a proper question because no one knows. Please frame your new question (if you want to post) more clearly.

Comment: to put it in simple word now god is typing here for your answer.. that is I have my antaryami  god who does the typing for me.. similarly for every jiva from Ameoba to Brahma, he is the doer of everything according to swabhava of Jiva (madhvacharya)

Comment: but you are not god essentially you are entity just like water mixed in milk you are there but god does all the action for you, According to advaita god is atma that is you, besides there is antraatma or paramatma who is doer of your action. based on past karma, vasena you had accumulated in your previous and current birth according to desire he does the action for you which you think its best for you, but i maynot best until unless you realize this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all whatever work Supreme Lord does he has no purpose to do it from absolute level perspective which I [discuss here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/what-exactly-is-a-leela-%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%b2%e0%a4%be-is-there-a-scriptural-definition-of-leela-%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%b2%e0%a4%be/16188#16188) and hence his activity is termed as Leela.

As for daily activity like what do Lord Shiva do daily in Kailash or what do Lord Vishnu do daily in Vaikuntha we can infer their daily activity from various Puranic sources and also from Itihasas. For eg. There are times when Lord Vishnu [sleeps](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/are-there-any-scriptural-references-of-the-trinity-brahma-vishnu-maheshshiva/20600#20600) in the Milky Ocean. There are times when Lord Shiva is engaged in meditation. 

Here is an example from [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm) about what Lord Shiva does:

> He has snakes for his belt, and his ears are adorned with ear-rings made of snakes. Snakes form also the sacred thread he wears. An elephant skin forms his upper garment. **He sometimes laughs and sometimes sings and sometimes dances most beautifully. Surrounded by innumerable spirits and ghosts, he sometimes plays on musical instruments. Diverse, again are the instruments upon which he plays, and sweet the sounds they yield. He sometimes wanders (over crematoria), sometimes yawns, sometimes cries, and sometimes causes others to cry. He sometimes assumes the guise of one that is mad, and sometimes of one that is intoxicated, and he sometimes utters words that are exceedingly sweet. Endued with appalling fierceness, he sometimes laughs loudly, frightening all creatures with his eyes. He sometimes sleeps and sometimes remains awake and sometimes yawns as he pleases. He sometimes recites sacred Mantras and sometimes becomes the deity of those Mantras which are recited. He sometimes performs penances and sometimes becomes the deity for whose adoration those penances are undergone. He sometimes makes gifts and sometimes receives those gifts; sometimes disposes himself in Yoga and sometimes becomes the object of the Yoga contemplation of others.** He may be seen on the sacrificial platform or in the sacrificial stake; in the midst of the cow-pen or in the fire. He may not again be seen there. He may be seen as a boy or as an old man. He sports with the daughters and the spouses of the Rishis. His hair is long and stands erect. He is perfectly naked, for he has the horizon for his garments. He is endued with terrible eyes. He is fair, he is darkish, he is dark, he is pale, he is of the colour of smoke, and he is red. He is possessed of eyes that are large and terrible. He has empty space for his covering and he it is that covers all things. Who is there that can truly understand the limits of Mahadeva who is formless, who is one and indivisible, who conjures of illusions, who is of the cause of all actions and destructive operations in the universe, who assumes the form of Hiranyagarbha, and who is without beginning and without end, and who is without birth. He lives in the heart (of every creature). He is the prana, he is the mind, and he is Jiva (that is invested in the material case). He is the soul of Yoga, and it is that is called Yoga. He is the Yoga-contemplation into which Yogins enter. He is the Supreme Soul. Indeed Maheswara, the purity in essence, is capable of being comprehended not by the senses but through only the Soul seizing his existence. **He plays on diverse musical instruments. He is a vocalist.** He has a hundred thousand eyes, he has one mouth, he has two mouths, he has three mouths, and he has many mouths.

Comment: He doesn't do anything, it just happens.

Answer (score 9):

God is an ambiguous term, it can indicate Supreme Personality of Godhead Bramhan(super soul) or it can indicate gods(devtas) that are merely jeevatmans(atmans subjected to birth and death).

So I will answer this question for both contexts

- Bramhan
- Devta's

---

**Context Bramhan**

If we are talking about Bramhan who pervades everything then, [BG 3.22](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-3-22/) clearly mentions that Bhagwan has no duties, he has no work to do, still he performs actions for setting an idealistic example for the jeevas(souls) to do nitya karmas and discharge their prescribed duties in the samsara.

> न मे पार्थास्ति कर्तव्यं त्रिषु लोकेषु किञ्चन।
>
> नानवाप्तमवाप्तव्यं वर्त एव च कर्मणि।।3.22।।
>
> O son of Pritha, **there is no work prescribed for Me within all the three planetary systems(tri lokas)**. Nor am I in want of anything, nor have I a need to obtain anything—and **yet I am engaged in prescribed duties**. [BG-3.22](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-3-22/)

So Bhagwan has no duties still he is engaged in all prescribed (when person performs swadharma) karmas.

Now there is a natural question:
How can Bhagwan possibly be engaged in prescribed activities while he has none of the prescribed activities for himself??

Bhagwan can do that because he is the antaryami(true self) inside all souls.

> ईश्वरः सर्वभूतानां हृद्देशेऽर्जुन तिष्ठति।
>
> भ्रामयन्सर्वभूतानि यन्त्रारूढानि मायया।।18.61।।
>
> The Supreme Lord is situated in everyone’s heart, O Arjuna, and is directing the wanderings of all living entities, who are seated as on a machine, made of the material energy. [BG 18.61](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-61/)

<sup>Please note that 'directing the wanderings' does not indicate that we don't have a free will, every action performed by the performer is controlled by five factors working behind the curtain controlling his/her activities(including his/her free will) [BG-18.14](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-14/) [BG-18.15](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-15/).</sup>

**Context Devta's**

Devtas are not independent beings they have their own prescribed duties for example Agni(the fire god) has the work to take all the offerings in the sacrifice(s)(yagnas) to the gods. Similarly different gods(devtas) have different duties and so they discharge their own duties by using their power provided by Bramhan.

Comment: It's good that you have explained meaning of "God", which is highly divided among Deva-s and Brahman and few more. BTW, it's recommended to use GambhirAnanda's translation for Gita as they are more accurate. Prabhupada's translations are usually erroneous. gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in

Comment: @iammilind I don't see any errors in these(aforementioned translations in the answer) translations, afa the prabhupada translation is considered I match it with Bhagwad Ramanujacharya's words and then post it. I prefer bhagvadgita.us because it provides max possible commentaries on a verse in a presentable manner.

Comment: I see. BTW, the word to word translation would be: *(1) BG 3.22 -- O PArtha, there is absolutely no duty for Me in the 3 worlds; Nothing remains unachieved or to be achieved; Yet I continue in actions. (2) BG 18.61 -- O Arjuna, the lord resides in hearts of all beings; Through illusion(mAyA), all beings are wandering mounted on a machine.* I also used to refer PrabhupAda's translation, however they seems bit far from the actual words. The volunteers in ISCKON had attempted to correct in past but there was a huge uproar. I understand your point on commentaries though.

Answer (score 3):

The word 'God' can be translated in many ways. It can mean the nirguNa Brahman, Who is described as the 'drasta sAkshi kevalo nirgunas cha : just Witness  of every activity), or to the Saguna Brahman or Ishvara (According to the Advaita-Vedanta, He is the Nirguna Brahman seen from within the Maya). The three gunas make Him do three activities simultaneously and ceaselessly : Creation by Rajo-Guna, Preservation by the Sattva-Guna and Destruction by the Tamo-guna.

The above is clearly mentioned in Srimad-Bhagavatam (10/2/28)

> tvamekah evAsya satah prasutis tvam sannidhAnam tvam anugrahas cha/tvan mAyayA samvritachetasas tvAm pashyanti nAnA vipaschito ye//

meaning: O God ! You alone **create**, **preserve** and **destroy** the worlds. Those who are deluded by Maya sees many forms of you [like Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva etc], but the wise ones know that you are always One.

The svarupa of God according to Srimad-Bhagavatam (3/26/3) is

> •anAdir AtmA purusho nirgunah prakriteh parah/pratyagdhAmA svayamjyotir vishvam yena samnvitam//

meaning : God (Purusha) is originless, devoid of any quality (nirguNa), all-pervading and infinite. He is always separate from the prakiti (consisting of the three gunas that create, preserve and destroy), is self-effulgent. So here **God in His real svarupa does nothing.**

That the God works ceaselessly has been mentioned in the **Gita**:

> 3.23 For, O Partha, **if at any time I do not continue vigilantly in action,** men will follow My path in ever way.
>
> 3.24 These worlds will be ruined if I do not perform action. And I shall become the agent of intermingling (of castes), and shall be destroying these beings.

By the way, Creation did NOT stop. This universe in finite as is time and this three activities are taking place in anything material continuosusly,Science including biology accept especially the latter.

**Shiva-PurAna** mentions that Ishvara is Lord Shiva Himself. He assumes five forms:

> Sivo Mahaswarachiva Rudro Vishnuh Pithamaha /
> Sansara Vaidyah Sarvajnah Paramatmeti Mukhyataha /
> Namashtaka midam nitya Sivasya Prati padakam/

So the five forms are Shiva, Mahesvara, Rudra, Vishnu and BrahmA (PitAmaha).
He assumes these five forms to perform five functions known as the '**Pancha**-**Kritya**-s:**Creation** or Srishti, **Preservation** or Sthiti, **Destruction** or Laya, Tirobhava or Nigraha (**concealment and Revival**) and Anugraha (**Providing salvation by grace**).These five are the constant activities of the Ishvara.

As BrahmA He does creation, as Vishnu He does preservation, as Rudra desrtruction, as Maheswara concalment and revival, as Shiva showering of grace and giving liberation.

Reference: http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/shivapuranam38.html

That God does do 'anugraha' and 'nigraha' is accepted by Srimad-Bhagavatam also (10/16/59).

According to the Devi-Bhagavatam (Canto 5, chapter 8, slokas 59

> tathA eshA devakaryaArtham arupA api svalilayA/karoti vahurupAni nirguNA sagunAni cha// meaning the Supreme Goddess is beyond all qualities [ and so inactive]. But to perform works for the welfare of the gods, She assumes various forms by various qualities (guNas).

According the Devi-Vhagavatam, MahamAyA is Brahman, ParamAtmA and God Herself (Reference: Sri Sri Chandi,Udbodhan, page 48).

According to the KAlikA-PurANa,

> God is called MahamAya.She covers the knowledge of the jiva as soon as the jiva is born.She binds them with attachment and greed (mamatva and moha) according to the child's impressions (sanskaras) of the previous births,She constantly hyponises the jiva by attaching them to thoughts, dsires and sensual pleasures and injects in them anger, lust and attractions.

So the above are the never-ending activities of Mahamaya, Who is God according to the KAlikA-purANa (Reference : Ibid. page 49).

I found this question from OP in a comment in response to another answer:

"**I mean** **god** **in physical appearance like before ...why not now like before?**"

This 'like before' has no meaning to me. In Hinduism God is NOT an individual residing somewhere with some particular form---- God is eternal and unfathomable and changeless in essence. He constatly assumes different forms for different activities. This is especially true for the Sanatana Dharma. I think the above quotations make it clear that such a question is without any basis with respect to our holy scriptures. **Yes, there are mentions of different lokas like Golaka, Vaikuntha, Shivaloka, Deviloka etc etc Where a particular form of God is said to reside with consort and live playfully.I think a moment's thought makes it clear that NO such loka can be accepted as THE Supreme Abode of GOD.It varies with the belief of the devotee.So we can never say that God reides at some particular loka and do some particular thing and not reside in the other lokas and not doing other things.**

Please see the concept of God from two puranas:

> Siva is not just the god of destruction, dwelling on the Himalayas or the cremation ground. He is the embodiment of renunciation and destruction of all evil. He is the personification of contemplation and divine consciousness. He is ‘the one Brahman, without a second, the All’ (Skanda Purana 4.1.10.126)
>
> Is Visnu merely the lord of protection and preservation? He is the embodiment of the divine Principle that permeates the entire universe in which the world-play of creation, preservation and dissolution is enacted. He ‘abideth in all.’ He is ‘all’. He assumes all forms (vide Vishnu purana 1.12.71)

So a minute study reveals that both are in fact just different forms of the SAME God.

**UPDATE**

**Which demons got killed today?**

According to the saints like Sitaramdas Omkarnath, the demons are actually different desires, passions and attractions that make the aspirants deviate from the spiritual path. As Sri Krishna says in Gita

> 10.11 Out of compassion for them alone, **I, residing in their hearts, destroy the darkness born of ignorance with the luminous lamp of Knowledge.**

This is the essence of the 'Demon-Killing' lila.Those who are walking along the spiritual path sincerely must have been getting God's grace with the demons in them getting killed by Him regularly. But it is kniwn only to the devotee and his/her Lord. This can be termed as His '**Anugraha**'.

On the otherhand, Gita also mentions

> 16.19 **I cast for ever those hateful, cruel, evil-doers in the worlds, the vilest of human beings, verily into the demoniacal classes.**

This can be termed as His '**Nigraha**'.

So the demons are getting proper treatment from Him at each instance. And from a broader perspective, He Himself is becomeing demon or evil and He Himself is slaying --- all is the Divine Play of the One.'Ekam vedam vibabhuv sarvam'.

Comment: I am not against , I wanted to know what big things god is doing now . Before god had done big things like killing big demons .And everybody on earth came to know about it . Now what big thing god is doing ,as we are not getting information about his doings ?

Comment: @AmruthA you are referring mostly to puranas and most of these are symbolical/allegorical.There is a deep philosophy underlying these which you can yourself find out if you minutely read ANY respected Purana with a neutral and good word to word translation.

Comment: @AmruthA kindly read in entirety and kindly avoid ISKCON translations.

Comment: @AmruthA He takes incarnation only when establishing dharma is required and His leelas explained also have hidden inner meanings

Answer (score 3):

I will take 'God' as 'Krishna' and answer the question.

Krishna in his two handed form eternally resides in spiritual planet called Goloka Vrindavan. He doesn't directly take part in creation. He expands as Purusha(Lord Vishnu) who takes care of primary creation(of ingredients). And then he himself takes care of maintenance, secondary creation is taken care by Lord Brahma, and destruction by Lord Shiva.

> SB 1.3.1: Sūta said: In the beginning of the creation, the Lord first
>   expanded Himself in the universal form of the puruṣa incarnation and
>   manifested all the ingredients for the material creation. And thus at
>   first there was the creation of the sixteen principles of material action. This was for the purpose of creating the material universes.
>
> sb 10.14.19:[Brahma to Krishna] To persons ignorant of Your actual
>   transcendental position, You appear as part of the material world, manifesting Yourself by the expansion of Your inconceivable energy.
>
> Thus for the creation of the universe You appear as me [Brahmā], for its maintenance You appear as Yourself [Viṣṇu], and for its annihilation You appear as Lord Trinetra [Śiva].

Krishna's Goloka Vrindavan is described in the 16th,17th chapter in [Vasudeva Mahtmay of Skanda purana:](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/13008/6/Chapter4_241-320p.pdf)

Krishna eternally resides as 16 year old boy there and eternally enjoys different pastimes with his cowherd friends, Srimati Radharani and other gopis, parents, cows and all residents of Goloka Vrindavana.

**What major works did god do today?**

In Goloka Vrindavan, He would have gone to forest with other cowherd friends to herd cows, perform different pastimes with gopis, gopas, animals etc.

He simply enjoys with his gopas, cows, gopis and other residents of Goloka daily. He doesn't bother anything else there.

Being unlimited, though he is eternally present in Goloka Vrindavan and does his pastimes without any interruption, he manifests in many forms like arca vigraha etc.

In form of Jagannath in Puri, he would have been worshipped and would have eaten a lot of food offered to him.

Simultaneously, he can reciprocate with any one anywhere in the world.

> BG 9.22: But those who always worship Me with exclusive devotion, meditating on My transcendental form – to them I carry what they lack, and I preserve what they have.

Brahma Samhita states(Text 6):

> The Lord of Gokula is the transcendental Supreme Godhead, the own Self of eternal ecstasies. He is the superior of all superiors and is busily engaged in the enjoyments of the transcendental realm** and **has no association with His mundane potency.

That is the aprakata form(not visible to ordinary souls). Only rare soul can see that. But, Krishna manifests same form when he descends to earth and all can see his form then.

> The Bṛhad-āraṇyaka Upaniṣad [5.1.1]:
>  oṁ pūrṇam adaḥ pūrṇam idaṁ pūrṇāt
>   
>  pūrṇam udacyate pūrṇasya pūrṇam ādāya pūrṇam evāvaśiṣyate

In this mantra, the word adaḥ [this] refers to the aprakaṭa [not manifested in the material world] form of the Supreme Brahman, which is the root from which the various prakaṭa forms of Brahman
emanate. Both aprakaṭa [manifested] and prakaṭa [unmanifested] forms of Brahman are perfect and
complete. That is the actual meaning of pūrṇam [complete or Absolute]: He can expand into an unlimited number of forms, and each one is as complete in transcendental power and attributes as His original form.

Brahman expands from His aprakaṭa form and appears in the material world in His prakaṭa form, displaying His rāsa-līlā and other transcendental pastimes. When the prakaṭa form of Brahman leaves
the material world and enters into the aprakaṭa form of Brahman, Brahman remains unchanged,
eternally perfect and complete.

Therefore the activities which Krishna performs in Goloka Vrindavan are also shown when he performs activities in earthly Vrindavan.

Since in spiritual world all are devotees, these are no demons, there may be just illusory arrangement of demons or rumors so that Krishna and his friends can enjoy.

There are innumerable material universes and Krishna may be performing similar lilas(in his prakata form) what he performed at the end of Dvapara yuga in some other universe now. Of course, he eternally performs activities in Goloka Vrindavana in aprakata form.

In short, Krishna enjoys eternally in Goloka Vrindavan planet in spiritual world. He expands as purusha avatars who take of creation, maintenance etc. He himself descends to the material universes to show trailer of his activities in spiritual world sometimes. When Krishna descends into material world, he may perform activities like killing demons etc.. that is just his secondary job, in spiritual world no such activities exist.

One of the reasons for Lord's avatar:

> SB 10.87.46: Śrī Nārada said: I offer my obeisances to Him of spotless fame, the Supreme Lord Kṛṣṇa, who manifests His all-attractive personal expansions so that all living beings can achieve liberation.
>
> SB 1.8.35: And yet others say that You appeared for the sake of rejuvenating the devotional service of hearing, remembering, worshiping and so on in order that the conditioned souls suffering from material pangs might take advantage and gain liberation.

Comment: yes absolutely.God only loves to play with the Gopis and cowherds.It must be some other Krishna who taught the Gita and told that OM iti eka aksharam Brahma etc.The Krishna who fought with other kings so bravely also must be someone else.I think Sri Krishna created a duplicate one to perform these activities as He created brahmma and vishnu as He cant leave the company of the gopis at all:)

Comment: you are correct to some extent. But it is same Krishna who spoke Gita etc.. that activity he does only when he descends to earth. in spiritual world no such activities exist..Earthly lila is a bit different from spiritual Goloka.. In earthly lila, he grows from childhood to youth and he leaves gopis and does other work also :)

Comment: i see. But 'tesham aham samudharta mrityu-sansara-sagarat' and 'tesham eva anukampartham aham ajnanajam tamah nashayami' etc of Git amust refer to some other Krishna as there He says He does it always:)

Comment: There is no contradiction. He does and can do many things simultaneously either directly or through his different features.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the question with limited human's buththi. As we are born as physical body, this is body is doing some physical work. can you tell how many your manas do approximately? If you can answer for this sincerely, i hope i can give answer for you.

Human's buthi is limited. Yogis and rishies shared the stories in which they shared the form gods in Cutcamam.

Earlier they did war with asur, it is not meaning now they are free. In within us, asur also there, sur also there. still war is happening. if we give space for bakthi, God kills the demon.

simply god is form energy. I think, you should change your question
.

Comment: i mean god in physical appearance like before ...why not now like before?