# Why Matsya and Kurma Avatars are not worshiped like other avatars?

Tags: vishnu, worship, avatars

Why Matsya and Kurma avatars are not worshiped like other avatars? Vamana as trivikrama, varaha has temples in south. Rama, Krishna, Balarama and  Narasimha avatars are worshiped and many temples are there across India. A separate question was asked about Balarama avatar. Kalki is yet to come.

Comment: Related [Are there any temples for Matsya, Kurma, and Varaha avatars?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2080/are-there-any-temples-for-matsya-kurma-and-varaha-avatars)

Comment: Temples are different  worship is different--How the relationship will come? Understand the question carefully; read the lines fully not in-between  and give your views. I have checked the duplicates when I typed the question and then only posted.

Comment: I said related not duplicate.

Comment: It is not also related--Given the facts where the temples are situated for avatars but in that question they asked for temples for varaha etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Matsya avatar incarnation was for fetching the stolen Vedas basically and to patent-save the prototype of Srushti-materials by that period Manu, as the Kala (time) was nearing Pralaya by deluge. The Koorma avatar was for providing the Devas their lost glory. As is evident from these fundamental causes, both avatars were not for humans but for celestials ! Hence why should humans worship those forms? Also Varaha avatar is concerned directly with Earth, our dwelling place and evolutionally fits in chronologically too as a starting point until today..! The Lord Varaha has also given instructions through his words called 'Charamasloka' as to how a man can stake his claim for attaining Salvation or Moksha..!

Comment: Nice answer. Please [register](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/187039) on the site.

Comment: @D.Kothandaraman Answer not suits the question. All the avatars were by Lord Vishnu. Dasavathara temple exists insouth iindia and all avatars are worshipped.