# Why all avatars are not equally popular and famous?

Tags: avatars

Why all of us do not like or pray to all the avatars or why people have belief in some avatars but not in others?

Why all avatars are not equally popular or famous?

Comment: Related NOT Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15194/why-matsya-and-kurma-avatars-are-not-worshiped-like-other-avatars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incarnation(avatar) who took birth from womb of a woman and lived specific age on earth, those incarnations are most popular and used to worship. Those incarnation who live with humans are popular amongs human. There are only two incarnation who live on earth and those are Rama and Krishna.

They are famous among humans because both lived with humans. During their age they did many great things which made them popular in whole world. For example: On Rama's time there were lots of things about Rama became popular:

- A stone turned into a beautiful woman when Rama touch her with his
  feet.
- Rama broke the bow of Shiva.
- Rama protects the sages by killing Tadka and many other demons.
- Rama killed Ravana whome even Gods were enable to kill.
- Dharma acharan of Rama known to everyone And so on...

By these examples people started to think Rama is not an ordinary person. He must be a divine source. So popularity of Rama in whole world is not an surprise. People actully experience Rama's divinity and spread this information generation to generation.

Same goes to Krishna. Krishna also did many actions which make people believe that he is Lord himself. People seen miracles of Krishna by their own eyes. Here are some examples..

- He lift whole mountain with his one fingure.
- Killed many rakshasa in his childhood.
- Kalia Naag incidents was seen by everyone in Gokul.
- Many was already aware of the fact that He was Lord himself and
  slowly everyone becomes aware of divinity of Lord Krishna. And so on...

So popularity of Krishna also can't be surprising since people has experienced his miracles by themselves.

Other incarnations of Lord Vishnu didn't live on earth and didn't spend time with humans that's why they are not much famous.

Vahmana avatar also lived with humans but he didn't perform much of divine action(except one) that can grab attention of many. Because of less Leelas of Vahmana avatar, his story was not long enough to be written like Ramayana. Hence this incarnation is not much famous because of less leelas.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Avatars of Lord Vishnu is famous because there were particular reason behind it and these Avatars were not in the form of human.That is the main reason and Lord Vishnu have not spread ***Dnyana*** in those avataras so they are not well known to people Only two Avataras are most famous these are Lord Ram, And Lord Krishna Lord Vishnu has spread so much knowledge and god Vishnu were in human Avataras so they spread lots of things about humanity and all.
But when it comes to avataras like Varah, Katchya, God were on particular task and then that avatara comes to an end.

That is the reason we are not so much aware of those Avataras.

Comment: Well, Sindhujaaksha has spread Gyaana in Matsya Incarnation, in fact, tge whole Matsya Puraana is discourse between Manu and Matsya Avatara of Krishna.

Comment: @AnuragSingh  I love how you use the various epithets - sindhujaksha, ksheerasagarasayana, ditisutas. Please continue :-)