# Which scriptures talk about the Kurma avatar of Vishnu?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, avatars, samudra-manthan, kurma

I would like to know more about the Kurma avatar of Vishnu. I know that Vishnu took the form of a tortoise to facilitate Samudra Manthana. Although, no other details are known. The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurma) is not of much help.

Astrologically, Kurma avatar is associated with Shani Graha.

Are there any scriptures which go into more details about this Avatar of Vishnu?

For those interested, here is a [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2080/are-there-any-temples-for-matsya-kurma-and-varaha-avatars) which talks about the temples of Kurma avatar.

Comment: Do you want Astrological association of Kurma with Shani or any info about Kurma?

Comment: Talk about means?anything specific?..In anycase.The Kurma Purana talks about the avatara..

Comment: I am looking for any information. And thanks, I did not know there was a whole Purana on it!

Comment: @AmitSaxena The whole Kurma Purana does not discuss only about the avatara..but the first chapter starts with it..

Comment: @Rickross Okay, thank you, I will have a look