# What is Hindu view on evolution?

Tags: vedas, puranas, science

In purans there is avtar of lord vishnu.
https://images.app.goo.gl/b2qMNkdSe2VCwegy5

But purans are mythology and should not be taken seriously as many scholar say.

So what is the actual human evolution in **vedas**. And not from purans.

And even if you take lord vishnu incarnation it is not completely true because the first life form start around 3.5 billion years age and it was a micro organism and not a fish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is evolution portrayed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/153/how-is-evolution-portrayed)

Comment: Well, no because their answers used purans and many scholar say purans should not be taken seriously. And I want an answer from vedas.

Comment: Yajur veda says Lord brahma started meditating on the lord.. and to create beings.. he taught of human first what it came is snakes..then he taught of human again doing penance for 50 thousand years he got Garuda birds again he never gave up he did penance 50 thousand years he got monkeys and again another 50 thousand years  he got human That is Mind born son Manu.. From Manu gave the human race.. that is where english etymology correctly says human born out of manu.. that is Man

Comment: But that doesn't link with evolution

Comment: you asked about vedas right vedas say the above about the creation like that only.. but its clear from veda after monkey man is born.. and also we confirm with Ramayana.. and your question is what great injustice done to hindu scriptures like ithias(history) and Puranas(stories of gods) just as mythology termed coined by invaders of india,

Comment: indians never believed their history as piece of lie as you have stated in the question.. but due to english and other wester invaders people where more of slave mindset started using the same terminology coined by britisher with slaves mentality of indians.. the word indian itself is slavery..

Comment: i can give you example they in south india especially in tamilnadu they started calling stragers as Sir which is title in UK.. but in TN any stranger is sir just because implanting of slavery english

Comment: @PrasannaR not only Tamil Nadu it’s even in Maharashtra. Just close it as scientific speculation. The users know the rules. He’s not a new user. He’s just here to draw comparisons between Islam and Hinduism and try to find points to refute Hinduism against science.

Comment: This is a valid question, why are people trying to close it?

Comment: See I think that humans lived on earth from start. They did not have evolution like Darwin thought. The first man was manu. And he probably was not a ape.

Comment: Note that I closed your question as a duplicate and not as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So how did humans actually evolve according to the Vedas?*

Most Hindu scriptures including the Vedas consider the universe around us to be a Creation (सृष्टि; sṛṣṭi) as opposed to something that can evolve on its own (without needing a Creator).

Here's what the Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad [says](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117939.html) on how humans and other lifeforms came about:

> **Chapter I > Section IV - The Creation and Its Cause**
>
> 1. **In the beginning, this (universe) was but the self (Virāj) of a human form.** He reflected and found nothing else but himself. He first uttered, ‘I am he.’ Therefore he was called Aham (I). Hence, to this day, when a person is addressed, he first says, ‘It is I,’ and then says the other name that he may have. Because he was first and before this whole (band of aspirants) burnt all evils, therefore he is called Puruṣa. He who knows thus indeed burns one who wants to be (Virāj) before him. (1.4.1)
> 2. He was afraid. Therefore people (still) are afraid to be alone. He thought, ‘If there is nothing else but me, what am I afraid of?’ From that alone his fear was gone, for what was there to fear? It is from a second entity that fear comes. (1.4.2)
> 3. He was not at all happy. Therefore people (still) are not happy when alone. He desired a mate. He became as big as man and wife embracing each other. **He parted this very body into two. From that came husband and wife.** Therefore, said Yājñavalkya, this (body) is one-half of oneself, like one of the two halves of a split pea. Therefore this space is indeed filled by the wife. He was united with her. **From that men were born.** (1.4.3)
>
>    (Commentary: He, the Virāj called Manu, was united with her, his daughter called Śatarūpā, whom he conceived of as his wife. From that union men were born.)
> 4. She thought, ‘How can he be united with me after producing me from himself? Well, let me hide myself.’ **She became a cow, the other became a bull and was united with her; from that cows were born.** The one became a mare, the other a stallion; the one became a she-ass, the other became a he-ass and was united with her; from that one-hoofed animals were born. The one became a she-goat, the other a he-goat; the one became a ewe, the other became a ram and was united with her; from that goats and sheep were born. **Thus did he project every-thing that exists in pairs, down to the ants.** (1.4.4)
> 5. He knew, ‘I indeed am the creation, for I projected all this.’ **Therefore he was called Creation.** He who knows this as such becomes (a creator) in this creation of Virāj. (1.4.5)
> 6. Then he rubbed back and forth thus, and produced fire from its source, the mouth and the hands...This is the super-creation of Virāj that he projected the gods, who are even superior to him. Because he, although mortal himself, projected the immortals, therefore this is a super-creation. He who knows this as such becomes (a creator) in this super-creation of Virāj.

Answer (score 3):

> What is Hindu view on evolution?

Evolution of all current lifeforms from small bacteria through natural adaptations over billions of years never happened. According to our scriptures, all lifeforms were [created by Brahma](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp039.htm#page_34), Prajapati, Kashyapa, and other devatas at the beginning of creation, and humans have always existed on earth. [We are currently in the 7th manvantara.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm#page_21)