# Are the next and previous universes same or identical?

Tags: time, creation, universe

We know that time is cyclic in Hinduism[[Time in Hinduism](https://www.learnreligions.com/the-concept-of-time-1770059#:%7E:text=Time%20is%20God,to%20exist%20in%20the%20Absolute.)]  and universes are created and destroyed every time.

So, are the new and old universes identical in every way?

Comment: Scientific speculations?

Comment: @Vivikta how it is a Scientific speculations can you explain it.

Comment: I think, a more accurate re phrasal should be.:- how can **you** explain that this question is not inciting scientific speculations (laws of physics)? ;))

Comment: @Vivikta because I am not asking the explanation of laws what I am asking is, "do the laws change after the creation of new universe"

Comment: I dont get it, Vedic followers profess Vedic knowledge as being scientific, but here when a valid question is asked, its down voted, lol

Comment: @Proxy I have linked it

Comment: No, I dont mean that. Dont intermix two highly distinct concepts. Within the scope of Hinduism, laws of physics are foreign. For physics, the concept of new universes remain hypothesis- a physicst can fix any laws to his new universe. But the laws within one universe can only be found by observation within that universe. I suggest the question can be remade- "so when new universe are created are they identical?". That would remove constraint to find laws of physics in sculptures.

Comment: [Related] [How does the names and events reoccur in different manvantara or Kalpa or different universes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10584/3500) and [Repetition of Time and Yugas in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3078/3500)

Comment: Next universe for whom?

Comment: @hanugm for all those souls(atma) who didn't attain Moksha.

Comment: @DarkKnight All soul's may not go tot he same universe.\

Comment: @hanugm that's not what is am asking. Anyway at least some souls will go to the same universe

Comment: @hanugm is the previous universe same as the new or next universe (identical). Do they have same laws of physics.

Comment: Yeah, some may go to the same universe and some may go to identical universes and some may go to universes with different laws of physics. So, your question is: can a person go to different universe or goes to same universe (w.r.t laws of physics).

Comment: @hanugm no no no noooo, my question is weather the new universe that will be formed will be identical to the old universes. It not about souls but it about universe.

Comment: @DarkKnight Yeah, I'm saying about the universes only.

Comment: you need to change the word, 'universe' to 'creation', then there will be no scientific speculation. (from Close votes review)

Answer (score 2):

See the following answer: [How is evolution portrayed?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/153/how-is-evolution-portrayed/16444#16444)

To quote, and to answer your question:

The Linga Purana explains some sort of evolution on a macroscopic scale:

> अतीतानि च कल्पानि सोदर्काणि सहान्वयैः ।
> अनागतेषु तद्वच्च तर्कः कार्यो विजानता ॥ १४ ॥
>
> atītāni ca kalpāni sodarkāṇi sahānvayaiḥ |
> anāgateṣu tadvacca tarkaḥ kāryo vijānatā || 114 ||
>
> “The past kalpas are such that they leave their consequences on the future ones along with (or including) the dynasties of Kings etc. and the same reasoning should be applied to future kalpas by the knowing man (i.e., the past has left its marks on the present and in the same way the future will carry the marks of the present).” [verse 1.70.114](https://archive.org/stream/LingaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/Linga%20Purana%20-%20J.L.Shastri%20-%20Part%201#page/n321/mode/2up)

A [kalpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(aeon)#Hinduism) represents a day (or night) of Brahma and amounts to 4.32 billion human years. Then 30 * 12 * 100 of these kalpas represent the life cycle of the universe so that leaves plenty of time for evolution to occur between those transitions.

Comment: That's not what I am asking, my question is weather new universe that has formed after the destruction of the old universes are identical in nature.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the universe re-created after each kalpa? Then according to the Linga Purana, they are similar but not identical.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to find excerpt from the text so I will just mention it what it said.

I a particular chapter of **Mahabharata** this is talked about and this is what the the lines were -

> Universe is created and destroyed over and over again and again and transition from one creation to another is like changing seasons, flowers which were present before in previous season are not seen in present one.

This is a clear indication that every fresh creation does not look same like the previous one. Like flowers and fruits around us are different in every season in same way the universe as seen now may not be same in another Kalpa.

P.S - I will try to locate this particular excerpt and add it to the answer but if anyone else remembers where it is please do feel free to inform in the comments.

Comment: I can't say that I agree woth your interpretation. The changing of the seasons is a frequent metaphor for change itself. Is there a commentatorial tradition that supports your view?

Comment: Even in this world, if a tree blooms into flower and then seeds a new tree; the new tree is not alike the old in all respects; nevetheless, we still says it is the same species of tree ...

Comment: @Mozibur its not my interpretation the text mentioned so directly that just like flowers around are different in any season amd cannot bw recognised with old ones Universe in consecutive kalpas is also different i didn't keep the answer lol because of inability to locate the entire thing in text.

Comment: Well, if it isn't your interpretation then it would make sense to name whose it is.