# Physical changes in other lifeforms in each Yuga

Tags: mahabharata, kali-yuga, yuga

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm In this section of the Mahabharata mentions how men physically change over time I am wondering if other life forms similarly change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> manuṣyāṇāṁ paśunāṁ ca pakṣiṇāṁ sthāvaraiḥ saha / 
> teṣāmāyurupkrāntaṁ yugadharmeṣu sarvaśaḥ // 
> ~ Matsya Purāṇa ([145.4](https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n541/mode/2up?view=theater))

*As per yugadharma, there's decline in the āyus of manuṣyas, paśus, pakṣis and sthāvaras (such as vṛkṣa) [with the decline of yugas (i.e. Kṛta → Tretā → Dvāpara → Kali) in a mahāyuga].*

> gavāṁ ca hastināṁ caiva mahiṣasthāvarātmanām // 
> krameṇaitena vijñeye hyāsavṛddhī yuge yuge / 
> ~ Matsya Purāṇa ([145.11b-12a](https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n541/mode/2up?view=theater))

*The go, hasti, mahiṣa, etc. and sthāvara (such as vṛkṣa), all undergo variations (hrāsa and vṛddhi) accordingly, during the different yugas.*

Therefore, as stated in aforementioned ślokas of Matsya Purāṇa, yugadharma affects the life-span & sizes of not only manuṣyas, but also paśus, pakṣis, & sthāvara (such as vṛksas).

Comment: Lovely answer so primarily plants, buffalo, elephants, and humans.

Comment: @Haridasa animals such as buffaloes, cows, elephants. It's not like buffalo, cow and elephant are the only animals, who undergo changes. And also birds too, undergo changes.

Comment: Very cool this has parrels to the basic theory of evolution ofc we are creationists.

Comment: I am curious that Mahabharata has any verses as well.